# Was "UTA III - Reincarnation" in the original Ghost in the Shell movie?

Tags: music, ghost-in-the-shell

We all know the iconic opening song of the original *Ghost in the Shell* 1995 movie. A haunting chorus of singers singing a traditional wedding prayer (from what I gather). Titled "UTA I - Making of Cyborg" ("*UTA*" means "song"), it is again heard later on as "UTA II - Ghost City" just before the puppet master is introduced.

Apparently, there's "UTA III - Reincarnation" that was never played in full in the movie. It's heard yes, at the end you hear the gongs at the beginning of UTA III, but it abruptly cuts to another song, which is a pity considering UTA III is awesome.

Did the original in-theatre movie play "UTA III - Reincarnation" but was later changed in the public releases?

Comment: I updated the full title according to the official OST listed on [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/ghost-in-the-shell-koukaku-kidoutai-original-soundtrack/910532068)

Answer (score 3):

I do believe so, Kenji Kawai's soundtrack was released on November 22, 1995, and it does contain the track "UTA III - Reincarnation".

All three contain the track:

- https://itunes.apple.com/gb/album/ghost-in-the-shell-koukaku-kidoutai-original-soundtrack/910532068
- http://wrwtfww.com/album/ghost-in-the-shell-original-soundtrack
- [https://www.amazon.com/Ghost-Shell-Kidoutai-Original-Soundtrack/dp/B00MVNA8F6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00MVNA8F6)

When Ghost in the Shell 2.0 was released, an updated version of the soundtrack was released on December 17, 2008. This also contained "UTA III - Reincarnation"

Comment: But like I said the dvd film that I have doesn’t have Uta III or rather it doesn’t play Uta III in full but only the beginning bell part.